# Swift iOS: passing object to view and back from view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm following some tutorials on Swift development, and I'm trying to figure out the best ways to pass information back and forth to different views.

One tutorial I'm using mentions using a global scope variable and not worrying about it. This is cool, but is this the only way? I'm worried that if I don't learn the proper way to pass objects back and forth, I'll be clueless down the line.

Currently, I have my main 'shopkeeper' class instantiating inside my first view's viewDidLoad() (a tableview). First, is that even the correct thing to do? Will this execute again when I come back to this view from another view?

Secondly, how do I pass my 'shopkeeper' class along to the next view (right now I'm getting to the next view by a BarButton action. Do I make my own UIBarButton class?

Comment: If I understand what you're saying correctly, it sounds like you might want to use a `weak` reference.

Comment: It sounds like you want your ShopKeeper to be a singleton

Comment: Are you using storyboards and segues? If so you'll want to read up on the `prepareForSegue` method -- there you can hand over data to the next view controller.